# $z^4 = -1$ solutions?

Tags: complex-analysis

z is a complex number, my question will appear at the end:

$z^4 = -1 = e^{i\pi + 2\pi k}$

If we now take the root of both sides we get

$z = \pm e^{\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{2}k}$

But in the answer they only take the exponent>0.  There are four answers, all of them have exponent>0.

What about exponent<0??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression should be $e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{4} +\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}$, where $k$ ranges from $0$ to $3$.

The case $k=2$ gives the negative of the case $k=0$, and the case $k=3$ gives the negative of the case $k=1$, so the $\pm$ is not needed.